# I am getting error while using retfofit with MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm, retrofit

I am trying to fetch data by using retrofit with MVVM Architecture.
When I wanted to print the data on console, it works.

But when I wanna use them on the `RecyclerView`, I get this error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.movieapp, PID: 4275
> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Here is my codes:

### MovieRepository

```
public class MovieRepository {

private static MovieService movieService;
private final MutableLiveData<List<Movie>> listOfPopularMovie ;

private static MovieRepository newsRepository;


public static MovieRepository getInstance(){
    if(newsRepository == null){
        newsRepository=new MovieRepository();
    }
    return newsRepository;
}
public MovieRepository(){
    movieService= RetrofitService.getMovieService();
    listOfPopularMovie=new MutableLiveData<>();
}

public MutableLiveData<List<Movie>> getListOfPopularMovie(String key,int page) {
    Call<MovieResponse> popularMovies= movieService.getPopularMovie(key,page);
    popularMovies.enqueue(new Callback<MovieResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MovieResponse> call, Response<MovieResponse> response) {
            listOfPopularMovie.setValue(response.body().getResults());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MovieResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            listOfPopularMovie.postValue(null);
        }
    });
    return listOfPopularMovie;
}
```

### MainViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
private MutableLiveData<List<Movie>> listOfPopularMovies = new MutableLiveData<>();
private MovieRepository movieRepository;


public MainViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    movieRepository = MovieRepository.getInstance();
}

public MutableLiveData<List<Movie>> getListOfPopularMovies(String key, int page) {
    listOfPopularMovies=movieRepository.getListOfPopularMovie(key,page);
    return listOfPopularMovies;
}
```

### MovieAdapter

```
public class MovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.MovieViewHolder> {
private List<Movie> movies;
private Context mContext;
public MovieAdapter(Context context){
    mContext=context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_view,parent,false);

    return new MovieViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MovieViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Movie movie=movies.get(position);
    String currentTitle=movie.getTitle();
    String imageUrl="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original";
    imageUrl +=movie.getBackdrop_path();
    try {
        URL url=new URL(imageUrl);
        Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        Drawable drawable=new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(),bmp);
        holder.image.setBackground(drawable);
        holder.title.setText(currentTitle);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(movies == null)
        return 0;
    return movies.size();
}
public void setMovie(List<Movie> taskEntries) {
    movies = taskEntries;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    LinearLayout image;
    TextView title;
    public MovieViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image=itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_image);
        title=itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_title);
    }
}
```

### MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MovieAdapter movieAdapter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
MainViewModel mainViewModel;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView= findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    movieAdapter= new MovieAdapter(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
    DividerItemDecoration decoration = new DividerItemDecoration(getApplicationContext(), VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(decoration);
    mainViewModel= new ViewModelProvider(this,ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(getApplication())).get(MainViewModel.class);
    mainViewModel.getListOfPopularMovies("9e2629973011b0744ce3b589dff1fb32",1).observe(this, new Observer<List<Movie>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Movie> movies) {
           movieAdapter.setMovie(movies);
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix 'android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exception happened because you use network in UI thread.
I found the problem in your **MovieAdapter** code.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MovieViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ......................
    URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
    Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(),bmp);
    holder.image.setBackground(drawable);
    .............................
}
```

So you used url.openConnection() code in onBindViewHolder method of MovieAdapter class.
But onBindViewHolder is called in UI thread.

**So, Answer is you should not call this function in onBindViewHolder method.**

My suggestion is you can use image load library such as Glide or Picasso.

https://github.com/bumptech/glide
https://github.com/square/picasso

if you use Glide, your onBindViewHolder method like this.

```
Glide.with(holder.image.getContext()).load(imageUrl).into(holder.image);
```

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: please accept my answer if it's helpful for you.